# Linear algebra, Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Let $Proj_\vec{u}(\vec{v})$ be the projection of $\vec{u}$ where
$\vec{u},\vec{v}\in R^2$. If we fixed $\vec{u}$ and let $\vec{v}$ be a variable, then how can we see $Proj_\vec{u}(\vec{v})$ as a function in,
$$Proj_\vec{u}(\vec{v}):R^n\to R^n$$
Do you think $Proj_\vec{u}(\vec{v})$ is a real linear function with respect to $\vec{v}$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Unsure, I'm fairly new to linear algebra and I came across this question and was wondering how to answer it. Any hints?

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Proj}{Proj}$Go back to the definition of a linear function. In particular, try to verify (or disprove) that $\Proj_u(v_1+v_2)=\Proj_u(v_1)+\Proj_u(v_2)$ for all $u,v_1,v_2\in\mathbb R^2$, and that $\Proj_u(kv)=k\Proj_u(v)$ for all $u,v\in\mathbb R^2$ and $k\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Great thanks a lot, super helpful!